# How to create a select list containing only numbers smaller than $x

Tags: php, html

I want to create a 'select' list, which has 'option'-s containing all positive numbers smaller than or equal to certain number '$available'.

The idea is to only let customers select an amount which does exceed the amount we have in stock.

I suspect this has something to do with 'for' and 'while' loops. This is what i got so far, although I think it might be closer to the truth to say I got nothing.

Setting up the array:

```php
<?php
$available = 4;
for ($i = 1; $i <= $available; $i++)
{
     $out_array[] = $i;
}
?>
```

And displaying it somehow:

```php
<select>
   <?php 
    echo $out_array;
   ?>
</select>
```

This only gets me the numbers themselves, but I do not know how to get them to be displayed inside a select list as options.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply do:

```php
<select required>
    <option value="">Please select amount</option>
<?php 

    for($i = 1; $i <= $available; $i++) {
        echo "<option value=\"{$i}\">{$i}</option>";
    }
?>
</select>
```

This will create a select box that requires one of the options to be selected on supporting browsers (all major desktop browsers).

Comment: Thank you so much!
I would have upvoted, but I need 15 rep.
Have a good day!

Comment: You are welcome. Once you confirm that an answer is indeed valid, it is recommended to accept it in order to mark the question as answered.

Comment: You can still accept the answer (assuming the problem is solved by this answer) by clicking on the check-mark outline beside the answer's text.